# How to practice Linux Kernel programming by coding sample programs for clarification

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I was trying to practice some kernel process management APIs as in http://reiber.org/nxt/pub/Linux/LinuxKernelDevelopment/Linux.Kernel.Development.3rd.Edition.pdf (Linux Kernel Development by Robert Love, 3rd edition).

I am not sure how to practice the code snippet given in the text book. I can understand the theory but do not find a way to practice. For example: I want to read a process `struct task_struct` to find it parent's process identifier or how many tasks are in which state or creating kernel threads etc? If I am not able to practice these then it would be hard remembering them. Such that these concepts remains embedded into my memory out of practice.

Comment: Doing it hands-on can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a char driver and within its open/read/write methods, access the task_struct which will be the current user-space process that is doing the operation. You can know the processes PID, PPID and other info.

Answer (score 0):

And, to inform you, You can get to know the PIDs and States of the processes by using bash command `ps -ef` or `ps ux`.
`ps` stands for Process Status. The command should be used to display the currently running processes on Unix/Linux systems.